# Bad audit question - failed audit on question that should have been closed

Tags: discussion

I just failed the following close vote audit https://superuser.com/review/close/354906.

The question is asking about an issue on a work pc in a corporate network.

As it stands the question should have been closed as off-topic "Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic".

However, as soon as the close button is clicked there is an immediate audit fail.

Can we please remove this question from review audits?

Comment: The off-topic reason posted above doesn't really fit the question - questions relating to domains are allowed on SU as far as I can remember (unless I'm just wrong, which happens)

Comment: @ekaj I would have to say "it depends". If your problem is with rights that are protected by domain policies such as admin rights then there is nothing we can or should do, it is up to your IT department. If your machine just happens to be on a domain but otherwise you have the power to do what you need to do then it's fine here.

Comment: I don't see it saying it's in a domain... Am I missing something?

Comment: Again, I'd like  to renew my request for a "DISPUTE" button when you get an audit result that you do not agree with. This would allow you to add comments and indicate the dispute.   Right now there is no easy way to identify those audit questions that are disputed so that the system can be improved (unless somebody really likes what it is now :-()